# Как вытянуть класс или id элемента с помощью PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть на странице div'ы. 
Нужно узнать их классы или айдишники и поместить в переменную. 
Пока пробую так. 
Того что мне нужно, не выводит.

```html
<?php    
$postclass = post_class();
       echo $postclass;
       var_dump($postlass);
?>
```

Comment: Не ясно зачем нужен такой функционал. Конкретизируйте задачу. Что вы в итоге получить хотите? Для чего их помещать в переменную?

Comment: Я хотел добавить блок на страницу, но чтобы он не был в контейнере который находится выше футера. Решил это созданием виджета и все.